# My question is about converting epoch millisecond from date in groovy

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy

I am generating epoch timestamp in milliseconds with the following code and it works (verified with https://www.epochconverter.com/). However, when we are setting timezone with JVM option -Duser.timezone=America/Toronto then for some historical dates time offset is differ by one hour. i.e Date=1950-11-19 (yyyy-MM-dd) correct epoch milliseconds -603313200000 (Sunday, November 19, 1950 12:00:00 AM GMT-05:00) but when timezone is set with JVM options value is -603316800000 and Epoch converted shows Saturday, November 18, 1950 11:00:00 PM GMT-05:00. I have used joda time lib with JDK 10

```
def static Long getEpochTimeStampInMilliSeconds(String simpleDate, String dateFormat) {

    Long retVal = null

    try {
        org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(dateFormat)
        DateTimeZone dtz2 = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Toronto")
        DateTime parsedDateTime = DateTime.parse(simpleDate, fmt).withZone(dtz2)
        retVal = parsedDateTime.getMillis()
    } catch (Exception e) {
        retVal = null
    }

    return retVal
}
```

date format is : "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: Could it have something to do with Daylight Savings?

Comment: *"when we are setting timezone with JVM option"* and then *"but when timezone is set with JVM options"*... Ehh?!? What?!? That's the same!!!!

Comment: Is there a specific backwards-compatibility reason you're using Joda?

Comment: it is related to daylight savings I have found total 839 days since Jan 1st 1900 to till now either one hour ahead or behind. My application is running in docker/Kubernetes. I have tried regular java library was receiving same so moved to Joda but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse with the correct time zone, so instead of calling [`dateTime.withZone(...)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withZone(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone)) after parsing is done, you need to call [`dateTimeFormatter.withZone(...)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withZone(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone)) before parsing with the formatter.

If the default time zone, as set by the `user.timezone` system property is `America/Toronto`, then the parsed `DateTime` value is already in that time zone, and `dateTime.withZone(...)` will do nothing.

If the default time zone is something else, then the parsed `DateTime` value is in that time zone, which would be a different UTC epoch millisecond value. Calling `dateTime.withZone(...)` will change the time zone, and hence the time value, but will not change the UTC epoch millisecond value.

```
def dtz2 = org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID("America/Toronto")
def fmt = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern(dateFormat).withZone(dtz2)
retVal = org.joda.time.DateTime.parse(simpleDate, fmt).getMillis()
```

---

**UPDATE**

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56798072/my-question-is-about-converting-epoch-millisecond-from-date-in-groovy/56798925?noredirect=1#comment100171935_56798925):

> I am receiving -603316800000 for 1950-11-19 for all scenario but correct value is -603313200000

Lets test which value is correct, using Java-Time API:

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Toronto");
System.out.println(Instant.ofEpochMilli(-603316800000L));
System.out.println(Instant.ofEpochMilli(-603316800000L).atZone(zone));
System.out.println(Instant.ofEpochMilli(-603313200000L));
System.out.println(Instant.ofEpochMilli(-603313200000L).atZone(zone));
```

*Output*

```
1950-11-19T04:00:00Z
1950-11-19T00:00-04:00[America/Toronto]    ⬅ Correct value
1950-11-19T05:00:00Z
1950-11-19T01:00-04:00[America/Toronto]
```

As you can see, the value you get (-603316800000) *is* the correct value for 1950-11-19 at midnight, Toronto time.

You get offset -04:00 for Toronto, because in 1950, DST lasted until Sun, Nov 26 at 2:00 am (see https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/canada/toronto), so the offset is correct for Eastern Daylight Time (EDT).

Don't know why you think -603313200000 is the correct value, but it is not.

Comment: Thanks Andreas for your response. I know timezone is already set so it will not change anything. I have tried your solution but received the same result. it is related to daylight savings. With your solution I am receiving -603316800000 for 1950-11-19 for all scenario but correct value is -603313200000. Can you please test at your end? Thanks again for your time

Comment: @Nazrul In computers, as far as time *offset* is concerned, GMT is the **same** as UTC, so whether you use GMT or UTC as reference will not affect the result.